# How to get the value from ion-select option

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an array of object called **options**.

this is my html code

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>place</ion-label>

        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="place" (click)="optionsFn(item);">
          <ion-option value="item" *ngFor="let item of options">{{item.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.price}}</ion-option> 
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>

{{salespriceOp}}

{{quantityOp}}
```

this is my .ts file code

```
product_option_value_idOp
  priceOp
  salespriceOp
  quantityOp
  skuOp
  nameOp

  options =  [
          {
            "product_option_value_id": "45",
            "name": "Bangalore Auto",
            "quantity": "12",
            "sku": "56876",
            "price": "100.00",
            "salesprice": "50"
          },
          {
            "product_option_value_id": "51",
            "name": "Hyderabad Auto",
            "quantity": "23",
            "sku": "56543",
            "price": "200.00",
            "salesprice": "60"
          },
          {
            "product_option_value_id": "52",
            "name": "Delhi Auto",
            "quantity": "14",
            "sku": "98767",
            "price": "300.00",
            "salesprice": "80"
          }
        ];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  optionsFn(item) {//here item is an object 
    console.log(item);
    this.product_option_value_idOp = item.product_option_value_id;
    this.priceOp = item.price;
    this.salespriceOp = item.salesprice;
    this.quantityOp = item.quantity;
    this.skuOp = item.sku;
    this.nameOp = item.name;
  }
```

> i am able to invoke the function but i am getting undefined in `console.log(item)`

Comment: its not working because you are calling `optionsFn` function from select tag. you have to add it on `ion-option` tag

Comment: @ranakrunal9 i think click functions should be used on  `ion-select` tag only if i use in `ion-options` tag i am not able to invoke the function itself

Comment: So for using it to ion-select you have to assign `[value]=item` in `ion-option` and need to use `gaming` in your `optionsFn` function. so remove argument from `optionsFn` and try to check.

Comment: The value of each option is being set to `nes`.  You are binding the value of select to something called `gaming` but you don't seem to have that in your component class.  Can you please post your full component class.

Comment: @Brad  i think you are mistaken i am trying to send the item object as a parameter `optionsFn(item)`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There were several things that together caused that error.
The first change there is that instead of using the `click` event like this:

```
(click)="optionsFn(item);
```

You should use the `ionChange` event that Ionic exposes like this:

```
(ionChange)="optionsFn();"
```

Also notice that since you use the `[(ngModel)]="place"` to bind the select element to one of your component's properties, you don't need to send the item as a parameter, because `this.place` will be the selected item when the `ionChange` event is triggered.

That's why your `optionsFn` method would look like this:

```
public optionsFn(): void { //here item is an object 
    console.log(this.place);

    let item = this.place; // Just did this in order to avoid changing the next lines of code :P

    this.product_option_value_idOp = item.product_option_value_id;
    this.priceOp = item.price;
    this.salespriceOp = item.salesprice;
    this.quantityOp = item.quantity;
    this.skuOp = item.sku;
    this.nameOp = item.name;
  }
```

Comment: in your plunker you are using the sale price and pice inside the ion-list itself but i need to display outside the list so only i try to send the entire object as parameter

Comment: But you can use `place?.salespriceOp` to show it where ever you want because it's part of the component.

Comment: If you want I can change the plunker to show you how to do it :)

Comment: how to make the options to be get selected at the first point because my ion-option initially showing null. i tried using  `checked="true"` but i am not able to see the selected option initially

Comment: In the constructor, you should do `this.place = this.options[0]` (if you want to select the first item).

Comment: No clicking the options field i need to show the price and name but after clicking any of the options i need to show only name in the field . and also i am not getting the field to show in the option at initial

Answer (score 1):

Use (ngModelChange) instead of (click) event.

```
(ngModelChange)="optionsFn()"
```

whenever the model value changed the ngModelChange will automatically call the relative function.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>place</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="place" (ngModelChange)="optionsFn(item)">
      <ion-option value="item" *ngFor="let item of options">{{item.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.price}}</ion-option> 
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="itemId = $event.target.value">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let s of itemIds" value="{{s.id}}">{{s.name}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

OR you can also do like this

```
<ion-select value="{{itemId}}" [(ngModel)]="itemId">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let s of itemIds" value="{{s.id}}">{{s.name}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

And in you `.ts` file just declare variable `itemId`;

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience insted of `(ionChange)="optionsFn();"` we can use the `[(ngModel)]="selectVariable"` which can be easily fetch later at the .ts file

Answer (score 0):

1. On ion-select element set `#id`  and `(ionChange)="anyFunc()"`

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="anyFunc()" #anyName>
  <ion-option value="{{item.id}}" *ngFor="let item of apicall?.items"></ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

2. Edit the ts file accordingly. Most importantly set `ViewChild` as a `Select` type from `ionic-angular`

```js
import { Select } from 'ionic-angular';

@ViewChild('anyName') theSelectObject: Select;

contructor() { }

anyFunc() {
    const theValue = this.theSelectObject.value;
}
```

and Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In html

```
<ion-select  (ionChange)="optionsFn($event)">
<ion-option    *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item.name"> 
  {{item.price}}</ion-option> 
 </ion-select>
```

In .ts

```
 optionsFn(event) {
 console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: need to add some text for explanation

Answer (score -1):

Check after making below changes :

// html change

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming" (change)="optionsFn();">
  <ion-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of options">{{item.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.price}}</ion-option> 
</ion-select>
```

//.ts change

```
optionsFn() {
  console.log(this.gaming);
  let item = this.gaming;
  this.product_option_value_idOp = item.product_option_value_id;
  this.priceOp = item.price;
  this.salespriceOp = item.salesprice;
  this.quantityOp = item.quantity;
  this.skuOp = item.sku;
  this.nameOp = item.name;
}
```

Comment: can you please check by changing `value="item"` to `[value]="item"`

Comment: i think [] this brackets are used in angular 2 to get the value for ts file to html