# how to get select option value in ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2

When choosing the option, its value will be stored in a variable, how will it be get value

driver.html

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-select interface = "popover">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let cg of routeData; let i = index;" value="{{i}}">{{cg.routeName}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

driver.ts

```
getRoute() {
    this.storage.get('token').then((tkn) => {
      this.headers.token = tkn;
      console.log("token Data: " + this.headers.token);
      this.driverProvider.getRoute(this.headers)
        .then(result => {
          if (JSON.parse(result.text()).response == "OK") {

            this.routeData = JSON.parse(result._body).stops;

            console.log("Route Name : " + JSON.stringify(this.routeData))  ;
          } else {
            this.err = JSON.parse(result.text()).res;
          }
        }, (err) => {
          console.log("Error is: " + err);
        });

    });

  }
```

output:[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from ion-select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503876/how-to-get-the-value-from-ion-select-option)

Answer (score -1):

Give `ngModel` to ion-select like

**html**

```
<ion-select interface = "popover">
     <ion-option *ngFor="let cg of routeData; let i = index;" value="{{i}}" (ionChange)="routeNameChanged(i,cg.routeName)">
         {{cg.routeName}}
     </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**ts**

```
export class ListPage 
{
    routeModel = "";
    constructor()
    {}
}

routeNameChanged(index,name)
{
  console.log(index+"=>"+name);
}
```

Comment: <ion-item>
    <ion-select interface = "popover" [(ngModel)]="routeModel">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let cg of routeData; let i = index;" value="{{i}}">{{cg.routeName}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>         .html file

Comment: Print this{{routeModel}} in  html and change value in dropdown

Comment: value get but Route Name also be get how can get route name

Comment: you need both index + name?

Comment: Yes Index and Name

Comment: Any other example

Comment: Did that call or not? Have check with console.log?

Comment: Not call and yes check the console.log

Comment: @ Paresh Gami you Right but my project not working in visual Studio Code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157448/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-jayprakash-singh).